# How to make application urls appear throughout the project?

Tags: python, django

My templates don't see URLs which are in my application, in code:

```
urls.py in project:

        urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
        url(r'^', include('search.urls')),
        url(r'^accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
    ]

urls.py in application:

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include('registration.backends.simple.urls')),
]
```

I have error and I know why:

```
NoReverseMatch at /accounts/login/
Reverse for 'auth_password_reset' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
<p>{% trans "Forgot your password?" %} <a href="{% url 'auth_password_reset' %}">{% trans "Reset it" %}</a>.</p>
```

But when I put `include('registration.backends.simple.urls')` in project urls 
everything is good. I know I can have a namespace my URL, but I don't want do this.

I want to ***see*** only my URLs from my app in all my application, and I don't want put my URLs in root `urls.py`. I want them in a separate file.

Can you do something about it ?

Comment: I dont' quite understand what you mean, you have two apps, first one is search and the second one is registration.backends.simple? What you expect to got?

Comment: Can you copy/paste the complete `urls.py` files, not just the url patterns?

Answer (score 0):

Need to terminate your regex strings with $, i.e,

```
r'^admin/$',
```

Comment: No you don't  -- this includes the admin urls, adding a `$` will break it.